# Not able to run the docker-compose up command

Tags: 20.04, snap, docker, composer

I am trying to run the docker-compose command. But, suddenly it got stop working. I am new in ubuntu. But, I am definitely sure that the following error is not from the docker-compose tool.

```
pct110@pct110-Ubuntu:~/alita$ docker-compose up
snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Are you using a snap version of Docker? 

Comment: @matigo I am not sure how did I install docker. I have installed it about 6 months ago in my linux system. But, I hardly use my linux system. How do I check that I am using which version of docker?

Comment: Maybe the problem is related to **apparmor on ubuntu**? But I can't reproduce the problem on my own server, can you provide more information about it?Maybe you can get inspiration [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70053614/snap-confine-has-elevated-permissions-and-is-not-confined-but-should-be-refusin)